# How to unzip gz file and and then use csv file?

Tags: python, gzip

I have been trying to unzip a .gz file and create a csv file from it. Then I need to sort that csv file. However, I keep getting errors after creating the csv file and sorting it.

I have created the file like so:

```
with gzip.open("test.csv.gz", 'rb') as f_in:
       with open("test.csv", 'wb') as f_out:
           shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out)
```

After creating the file I read in the sorted csv file like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as input:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input, delimiter='\t')
    first_row = next(reader)
```

However I keep getting the following error from the last line of the above code.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What am I doing wrong with either opening unzipping the gz file or opening the csv file?

Comment: This code works for me. I used this for my file: "first name,last name\nEric,Idle\nJohn,Cleese\n". Then I gzipped it. Then I ran your code. One warning: it's dangerous to use `input` as a variable because it will clobber the built in input() function. My guess is your original test.csv file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Your `test.csv.gz` file may have been compressed twice.

Answer (score 2):

gzip's magic number is 0x1f 0x8b... so that error means it's probably still gzip'd.